# Using a Button to add text to a text field value that is contained within a UITableViewcell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I'm looking to get a `UIButton` to add its title value to the currently selected `UITextField` that's contained within a `UITableViewCell`.

I have a row of buttons with common phrases that a user might use, such as "#CompanyName". I have set the common phrases as the title of the buttons. Just below the row of buttons I have a `UITableView` with cells each containing several static labels and a text field. I want to allow the user to press one of the buttons above the table view to add the button's title value to the text field that is currently being edited.

I have managed to do this as a test using a text field and buttons both being outside of the table view using:

```
    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        buttonTitle = sender.titleLabel!.text!
        testOutlet.text = "\(testOutlet.text!) \(buttonTitle)"
```

Now my question is how would I make this "testOutlet.text" dynamic so it only knows the text field that's being edited. I've looked into `textFieldDidBeginEditing` but couldn't figure it out. I have also tried defining the indexPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know which `UITextField` is currently being edited. To do this, you can use the following code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // code ...

    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        buttonTitle = sender.titleLabel!.text!
        oActiveTextField?.text = "\(oActiveTextField?.text ?? "") \(buttonTitle)"
    }

    fileprivate var oActiveTextField: UITextField?
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    // code ...

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: yourIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! YourTableViewCell
        cell.textField.delegate = self
        // TODO: configure cell
        return cell
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        oActiveTextField = textField
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        oActiveTextField = nil
    }

}
```